# Touch area changing on custom UIButton with image and title on landscape mode

Tags: iphone, uibutton, landscape

I'm trying to build a button that looks like the icons on the iphone , with an image and a title bellow.I'm working in landscape mode.
I have a custom button on the IB with image and title and inside the code I use the methods :

```
[aButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60.0, -50.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
[aButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-10.0, 29.0, 0.0, 0.0)];
```

my problem is that the area that react to the touch events is very small and is on the top left of the button , another problem is that if I change my button size I have to calculate again manually the values for these 2 functions.
Is there any easy way to do it?and if not how can I fix the touch area?
thanks
Gilad

Answer (score 1):

well , I just removed the NIB file and created a new one and everything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this one as well, but didn't see the limited touch area until recently.  Rebuilding the nib now and it's working.  Thanks for plowing this ground.